# Problem concerning neutral elements in group theory

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group with an element $x$ for which stands that $xyx=y^3$ for every $y \in G$. Prove that $x^2=e$ and $y^8=e$ for every $y \in G$.

This problem doesn't seem so difficult to me, though I don't really know how to start. I'm kind of lost in circular reasoning.

Comment: What if you take $y$ to be some (well-chosen) power of $x$? Once you have proved that $x^2=e$, remark that $xyx=xyx^{-1}$.

Comment: Suppose you proved that $x^2=1$, then $x=x^{-1}$ and $x^2yx^{-2}=y$. Hence $y^9=y$ which implies that $y^8=1$.

Comment: Thank you both! These comments really helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, suppose $xyx = y^3$ for every $y \in G$, then this holds in particular for $y=e$ the identity element. That $y^8=e$ requires a little but i will give a little hint:

$y^8=y^3 y^3 y^2$

Now if you substitute $xyx$ for $y^3$ in this and work around with it, you should get the right answer, $y^8=e$.

Comment: Thank you for your insights!